# How can I copy a file from 1 folder to another folder in S3 using lamda function located in the same bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is there a way to copy files from Folder in bucket 'A' to another folder in the same bucket 'A' using Lamda functions and triggers or that can be achieved by only by copying from 1 bucket to another bucket only ?

Please note that , I am able to achieve it from 1 bucket to another using lambda function.

Is there a probable solution as , if we give source and destination as same bucket it will go into infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  If you have a specific issue, please show a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Why do you say that it will cause an "infinite loop"? Are you saying that there is an Amazon S3 event configured on the bucket that is triggering an AWS Lambda function that is doing the copy? If so, then yes, this can cause a loop. The S3 Event should be configured **only to trigger on the folder receiving the initial object**. It should _not_ be configured to trigger on the entire bucket.

Comment: if re.search("foldertotest", key1): 
        s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, dst_bucket, dst_file_name)

I have used the above way to trigger the lamda , however I want to load it into a separate folder in the same bucket . Can you please tell me how to hardcode it or if any other way to load it  for the destination folder . Hope I am clear with my explanation .

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to stop execution if the file doesn't have your required source folder prefix. The lambda function will still get triggered on the event, but that's a compromise you'll have to make if you want to use the same bucket for source and destination.

Comment: if re.search("foldertotest", key1): 
        s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, dst_bucket, dst_file_name)

I have used the above way to trigger the lamda , however I want to load it into a separate folder in the same bucket . Can you please tell me how to hardcode it or if any other way to load it  for the destination folder . Hope I am clear with my explanation .